# Should umbraco & umbraco_client be checked in to source control?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Just installed the latest Umbraco (7.2.1) package via NuGet. My development environment is as follows:

- Umbraco is installed installed on IIS8 as shown below and is all up and running.
  [image: Umbraco app]
- My Visual studio project is set up as shown below (For the sake of clarity, any folder/file excluded from project is not in included in my source control.

  [image: Visual Studio project]
- The content folder houses all scripts, images & css
- On build - bin, config, content, masterpages, usercontrols, Views, xslt, default.aspx, Global.asax & the transformed Web.config are copied to the IIS instance (I don't like running Umbraco in the same place as my project, it just seems messy.)

Is this an appropriate way of developing for Umbraco? Am I missing anything, my biggest concern is whether or not I should include the umbraco & umbraco_client folders in version control and in the post build action. Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is some debate over what should and shouldn't be in your repository and ultimately it comes down to personal preference. I used to only add custom files and files that I changed from the Umbraco install such as the config files however since the introduction of the Nuget package I do put all but the binaries into source control because when I upgrade via Nuget later on I can easily see changes and merge customisations back in.

It saves a lot of hassle running Umbraco directly (IMO) especially if you make any changes via the UI and  if you're not running it directly then there is little point really in using the Nuget package because you will end up with a bunch of unused files in your project. In your situation you might as well keep your project clean and do a manual install into the location IIS is using for the site and only keep files in your project that you have created.

This is only my opinion so take from it what you wish but hopefully it is of some help.

Simon